# In ASP.NET and HTTP/2 and gRPC, a request scope is created when I connect to the endpoint or on every call instead?

Tags: asp.net-core, grpc-c#

There is something blowing my mind.

I have a gRPC Client in a Windows Forms Application that uses HTTP/2 protocol to communicate with my gRPC service, however, my question is: if I have a single connection, but I make multiple calls (with the same client instance), is this is considered a single request in the endpoint side or instead ASP.NET creates a request scope for every call?

I discovered this by mistake, because I was applying EagerRetry, so multiple requests are made to the server and the first success request is returned, but this caused an issue in my server. A DbContext Exception was thrown because it was being accessed by multiple threads at the same time. I was awaiting every call and my DbContext Lifetime was Scoped, so I know I was not violating this rule.

Then, I wondered if a request scope in the server side was created when I connect to the client or on every call instead.

I hope I was clear with my question.

Alirio.

Comment: Please share some [mre].

Comment: Without full knowledge of gRPC on ASP.NET, typically gRPC libraries expose RPC context and lifetimes in their APIs, but do not really expose connections as a concept.